# MySQL proper join method for one-to-many relationship including and excluding right table

Tags: mysql, join

I've been trying to solve this MySQL issue...half of the problem is wording my question, I apologize if this has been solved before, I did a lot of searching but wasn't able to find a solution.

I have two tables, called orders and order_items
Each order can contain many order items.

I need to do a search that returns orders that contain only one order item and not another, then vice versa.

To illustrate this point:

Table orders

```
order_id
1
2
3
```

Table order_items

```
order_item_id | order_item_type | order_id
1             | A               | 1
2             | A               | 2
3             | B               | 2
4             | B               | 3
```

What I need to do is to get orders that include only item A, only item B, and both.

As you can see Only Item A should return order 1, only item B should return order 3, and both should return order 2.

Despite all my best attempts I cannot get anything working. Here is the current attempt at returning orders with ONLY item A

```
    SELECT *
    FROM orders
    LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items
    ON order_items.order_id = orders.order_id
    WHERE order_items.order_item_type IN ('A')
    AND order_items.order_item_type NOT IN ('B')
    GROUP BY orders.order_id
```

As an experienced person can probably guess looking at my attempt, this returns both order 1 and order 2. I think this could probably be done with a subquery, but I believe it can be done with a proper join...just not sure how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: When you refer to ONLY item "A", or ONLY "B", or "BOTH".  If any of the orders have any other type such as "C", "D", "E", do you want to exclude those orders that HAVE ANY or MORE of "C", "D", "E"?  Also, does it matter if one order has 10 instances of "A", 2 of "B", just as long as it has A MINIMUM or 1 "A" and/or 1 "B" ?

Answer (score 0):

when selected single order_item:

```
SELECT i.* FROM order_items i
WHERE i.order_item_type = 'A' AND
  (SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = i.order_id) = 1
```

selected two order_item:

```
SELECT i.* FROM order_items i
WHERE i.order_item_type IN ('A', 'B') AND
  (SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = i.order_id) = 2
```

and join `orders` table as you like.